# Get *.proto files based on c# classes

Tags: protobuf-net

I have following use-case: there are several assemblies decorated with ProtoContract classes and I would like to generate proto files based on assemblies. So the question is how it can be done?

My first intention was to use Serailizer.GetProto but it is generic method which doesn't work for me because I only know class type in runtime.

Also why in r480 GetProto is not impelemented?

I'm aslo aware about VS08/10 but it doesn't seem to help in my scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For info, I just pushed a new commit of this in v2. Experimental, and needs lots more testing - but it does *something*!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to use the `Serializer.GetProto` method with a little reflection:

```
var method = typeof(Serializer).GetMethod("GetProto").MakeGenericMethod(type);
Func<string> getProto = Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<string>), method);
var proto = getProto();
```

Comment: Great, thank you... It's all my poor knowledge of reflection capabilities. Also Func<string> not Action<string>.

Comment: Minor note; you don't need to create a delegate for this; you can just use `string proto = (stirng) blah .MakeGenericMethod(type).Invoke(null,null);`

Comment: @MarcGravell A good point. I generally cache such functions based on type (since the subset of types that will be used are generally limited) and invoking the delegate is more performant (when called multiple times). As a result, it's become the defacto way for me to write such code. Also, I think the `Delegate.CreateDelegate` methods are not too well known, so figured I'd give them a bit of air time...

Comment: @rich.okelly since the output doesn't change, it would be more efficient to just cache the string by type

Comment: @MarcGravell In this instance yes, I was referring to the generic case.

Answer (score 4):

> Also why in r480 GetProto is not impelemented?

Because I have limited time, and lots of requests. I've had a lot of people asking me about `GetProto` lately, so I'm bumping that upwards on my list. I have to prioritise work on features in terms of benefit, effort against likely usage. `GetProto` isn't "core" to serialization, but is something I want to continue to support. It just takes effort. The usage of this feature is such that I didn't feel it justified delaying the v2 code-base.

The good news is that the core of v2 is non-generic, with the old generic API purely maintained for compatibility. So when I *do* re-implement this, it will be entirely usable without generics.

---

Update: an experimental cut of this has been comitted in r545. It passes the v1 tests, but: there weren't many v1 tests on this feature! So: I'll be adding more tests for this shortly.